# Are your git repositories accessible by others?

Tags: heroku, github

I am putting my code onto git-hub so it can be deployed by Heroku. Will anyone (other than me) be able to access and view the repository that I make? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the PRICING menu in the home page.

> Plans for all workflows
>
> GitHub is free to use for public and open source projects. Work
>   together across unlimited private repositories with a paid plan.

Comment: So you must pay for a heroku paid plan in order to have a private git repo?

Comment: Your question was about Git-hub. As it says you have to pay to have a private repo.

Comment: is there any possible way to deploy on heroku for free while having the source be private?

Comment: I wouldn't know. Try asking a different question.

Comment: Thank god. You can alternatevely use dropbox instead which allows for private and free file hosting. heroku supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your question is **Yes**, If you have a free GitHub account you can only create public repositories. 
There are several ways you can solve your problem with out actually paying to GitHub.

1. You can use Heroku Git
2. You can use dropbox

In both of these ways you can have your code private

[image: Heroku Git or Dropbox]